# Slow select from one billion rows GreenPlum DB

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, cassandra, greenplum, bigdata

I've created the following table on GreenPlum:

```
CREATE TABLE data."CDR"
(   
   mcc text, 
   mnc text, 
   lac text, 
   cell text,
   from_number text,
   to_number text,
   cdr_time timestamp without time zone
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE,appendonly=true, orientation=column,compresstype=quicklz, compresslevel=1
)
DISTRIBUTED BY (from_number);
```

I've loaded one billion rows to this table but every query works very slow.

I need to do queries on all fields (not only one),
What can I do to speed up my queries?

Using PARTITION? using indexes?
maybe using a different DB like Cassandra or Hadoop?

Comment: What kind of queries do you issue? Give some examples, please. Speaking about "slow" - without detailed HW specs, installation parameters and query you run (with explain plan) it is hard to say what is "slow" and what is "fast" for your system

Comment: Of course you need index, but not for the `SELECT fields` but for the field you use on `WHERE`

Comment: @0x0FFF I'm searching for guidelines on how to create the DB properly, currently the query takes hours (7-8 hours), and the queries I'm doing are simple select * using different where clauses

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza this is an easy case, but I'm using where for all fields, so I need to index them all? on the GreenPlum they are recommending partitions

Comment: You cannot just say "you need index" without seeing the queries and the data. It is obvious that making a full scan over huge amount of data will take huge time. For example, I see "cdr_time" here, which makes me think you are working with CDRs for some telco. Logically you should partition by cdr_time daily if cdr_time is usually participating in your query. Then if you query from-to numbers, they should be indexed. Move all these fields (cdr_time, from_number, to_number) to the beginning of the row. Create table as row-oriented

Comment: If you're having trouble with SELECT * queries - how many rows are you expecting to return from the query? Which bit of the query process is slow - local scan on each segment; motion of results to the master; returning data from the master to the client? An EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query would help you figure bit out.

Answer (score 4):

This highly depends on the actual queries you are doing and what your hardware setup looks like.

Since you are querying all the fields the selectivity gained by going columnar orientation is probably hurting you more than helping, as you needs to scan all the data anyway. I would remove columnar orientation.

Generally speaking indexes don't help in a Greenplum system. Usually the amount of hardware that is involved tends to make scanning the data directory faster than doing index lookups.

Partitioning could be a great help but there would need to be a better understanding of the data. You are probably accessing specific time intervals so creating a partitioning scheme around cdr_time could eliminate the scan of data not needed for the result. The last thing I would worry about is indexes.

Your distribution by from_number could have an impact on query speed. The system will hash the data based on from_number so if you are querying selectively on the from_number the data will only be returned by the node that has it and you won't be leveraging the parallel nature of the system and spreading the request across all of the nodes. Unless you are joining to other tables on from_number, which allows the joins to be collocated and performed within the node, I would change that to be distributed RANDOMLY.

On top of all of that there is the question of what the hardware is and if you have a proper amount of segments setup and resources to feed them. Essentially every segment is a database. Good hardware can handle multiple segments per node, but if you are doing this on a light hardware you need to find the sweet spot where number of segments matches what the underlying system can provide.

Comment: I tend to disagree with your statement on indexes. They don't help in Greenplum for analytic workloads, but for this use case index on phone number would clearly make sense as this is the field with high selectivity. In the field I've seen ~20x performance improvement for CDR data lookups caused by indexes

Comment: I agree that in some instances indexes do help and do make sense and this may be the case. I don't think blanket statements can be applied and it'll depend on what the query pattern is, the best thing to do is test with and without and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

@Dor,

I have same type of data where CDR info is stored for a telecom company, and daily 10-12 millions rows inserted and also heavy queries running on those CDRs related tables, I was also facing the same issue last year, and i have created  partitions on those tables on the **CDR timings column**.

As per My understanding GP creates physical tables for each partition whereas logical tables created in other RDBMS. After this I got better performance with all SELECTs on these tables. Also I think you should convert text datatype to Character Varying for all columns (if text is really not required) I felt DB operations on Text field is very slow(specially order by, group by)

index will help you depends on your queries in my case i have huge inserts so i didnt try yet

If you are selecting all the columns in select so no need of Column Oriented table

Regards